# Unexpected error - MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidQuestion

Tags: asp.net, security

I try to create user without passwordQuestion and answer.

But I always get an error

> MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidQuestion

```
string question = string.Empty;
string answer = string.Empty;
MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.CreateUser(user.Login, password, user.ContactInfo.EMail, question, answer, false, out createResult);
```

web.config

```
 requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using null instead of String.Empty for both question and answer.

Comment: well not really... because you are not passing in null ASP.NET thinks that the strings you trying to use the string you are passing in as the question and answer. and o.f.c the question cannot be empty :)